# inflating a layout in recyclerview in horizontal and vertical, FlexboxLayout with recycler view add view horizontal automatically vertical

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a layout that is inflated in an activity. Now all the info are displayed in vertical as shown in the following. [this is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v62Fq.jpg)

but what I want it to be is three textView should come horizontal and then next three should come as a next row and so on. I have posted the way it should look at bottom.[this is how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp4do.jpg)

this is the layout that has recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_my_groups"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="onOutsideClick"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_selected_groups" />
```

and the bottom is a separate layout with just a textView that I am using to inflate.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/tv_group_name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="8dp"
         android:background="@drawable/chip_drawable"
         android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAllCaps="false"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black"
         android:textSize="14sp" />
```

and the kotlin activity where I have inflated the layout

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GroupsViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.groups_item_row, parent, false)

    return GroupsViewHolder(view)
}
```

sorry if my code is not sufficient.

**Required output**
Is there any way that I could implement that
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a complete example

**Step 1:**
add implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0' in build.gradle

Note that starting from 1.1.0, the library is expected to use with AndroidX. Please migrate to AndroidX if you use 1.1.0 or above.

Please use 1.0.0 if you haven't migrated to AndroidX.

**Step 2:** Activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flexDirection="row_reverse"
    app:justifyContent="center"
    app:alignItems="center"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Android"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="iOS"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Windows"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Linux"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Unix"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="MaxOS"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Java"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="C++"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Python"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Kotlin"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Hadoop"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Solr"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexbox_item_background"
        android:text="Lucene"/>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

**Step 3** flexbox_item_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <corners android:radius="5sp"/>

</shape>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Step 3** FlexboxLayout with recyclerview

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: bro I hope this works but do you know how to implement this in kotlin.

Comment: Are you facing any specific problem with kotlin, it has very less java code,  if you will paste this code in android studio it will automatically convert the code to kotlin, if you would copy in kotlin file.

Comment: it shows type mismatch, when I copy this code and paste this code, after it is converted to kotlin. like required is RecyclerView.LayoutManager but found FlexboxLayoutManager in the layoutManager passed in setLayoutManager()

Comment: Can you share the snapshot ?

Comment: how to share here, should I post it in my question or is there someother way

Comment: screen shot is in this link                                                    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LOoxOhXSoZgExgxrniC0FvMBl0rkAAxe

Comment: I guess it is because you have mentioned gridlayouanager as RV layout manager

Comment: so what should I do now

Comment: If you found it helpful please don't forget to update and mark as answer

Comment: I commented the previous code and tried still the error says type mismatch

Comment: found the mistake, used wrong dependency. Now it works. Thank you bro for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Google's FlexBox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) for this. It will automatically space the items to fit the screen in any way you specify it.